# FontAwesome 5 Icons with Outlines Not Aligning

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to prototype a simple "like" button using FontAwesome 5. Clicking it should toggle between a filled red heart icon and an unfilled black border heart icon. The thing is that I want the black border to stay around the heart when it fills. The JS is easy enough, but to create the border, I'm stacking a Regular styled FontAwesome heart on top of a Solid one, yet they're not lining up correctly. I get the red inner heart overflowing the border and spilling out the sides of the outline.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.like')].forEach(heart => {
    heart.addEventListener('click', () => {
        heart.classList.toggle('liked');
        let fill = heart.querySelector('.fill');
        if (heart.classList.contains('liked')) {
            fill.style.opacity = '100%';
        } else {
            fill.style.opacity = '0%';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.like {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}
.like > .fill {
    color: red;
    opacity: 0%;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="like fa-stack">
    <i class="fas fa-heart fa-stack-1x fill"></i>
    <i class="far fa-heart fa-stack-1x border"></i>
</div>
```

Since FA5 replaces the icons with SVG, things like border and text-shadow don't work. I even tried things like targeting the path element inside and setting its stroke width and color, but I can't fade out the middle like that, and using it with this stack still has misalignment problems.

How do I make a simple bordered heart with FA5 whose solid interior can fade in and out on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of stacking, set a stroke on the SVG itself, and toggle the fill color instead of opacity.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.like')].forEach(heart => {
    heart.addEventListener('click', () => {
        heart.classList.toggle('liked');
    });
});
```

```css
.like {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}
.like > .fill {
    color: transparent;
    transition: color 0.25s;
    stroke: black;
    /* The stroke width is huge because the svg itself is ~512x512, which is then scaled down */
    stroke-width: 50px;
}
.like.liked > .fill {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="like fa-stack">
    <i class="fas fa-heart fa-stack-1x fill"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, this is a much better solution than what I came up with! Thank you! I don't work with SVG basically at all, so I was under the impression if I changed the color property to transparent it would override the stroke color. Apparently not! Thanks again!

Comment: If you look at the output of the fill, the SVG uses `fill="currentColor"`, which is a common way to color SVGs from the text color. The `stroke` isn't defined, so your css class can target and define it. Note that the border FA icon is actually a punched out icon that still uses fill, it has more definition in the svg path.

Comment: Downside with this approach is that the border pixel width is not defined in screen pixels due to the scaling, but it does give you more control than the FA border icon might.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution 5 minutes after posting this, despite spending hours on it before. Isn't that the way it always goes?

The solution is to simply add the data-fa-transform attribute to the fill heart to shrink it by 1px so it fits inside the border:

`data-fa-transform="shrink-1"`

Yup, that's it.

Comment: I'd suggest to make this the accepted answer then. Don't worry about it being your own answer  - ultimately it is the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I accepted @mix3d's answer, because it's better than my own solution :D